# Calculate the rolling mean by group with conditions for each rows in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create a `rolling_median` column as follow:

For each row:

- Filter the DataFrame to only keep rows of the same `Category`, having `Date_B < my_current_row.Date_A`
- Sort this filtered DataFrame by `Date_B`
- Calculate the median of `Value` using the N last entries with my filters : for example, if N=2, I will use the last 2 rows that respect my filtering to estimate the mean for my current row

Doing it using iterrows is doable but is not scalable.
Do you have an idea how to do it in a more "Vectorized" way with less complexity ?

Please find a snippet on how to generate a similar dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Sample DataFrame (replace this with your actual DataFrame)
data = {
    'Category': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
    'Date_A': ['2023-07-08', '2023-07-09', '2023-07-11', '2023-07-12', '2023-07-13', '2023-07-08', '2023-07-09', '2023-07-11', '2023-07-12', '2023-07-13'],
    'Date_B': ['2023-07-08', '2023-07-10', '2023-07-12', '2023-07-12', '2023-07-13', '2023-07-08', '2023-07-10', '2023-07-12', '2023-07-12', '2023-07-13'],
    'Value': [10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55]
}


df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Convert 'Date_A' and 'Date_B' columns to datetime type
df['Date_A'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_A'])
df['Date_B'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_B'])
df['rolling_mean'] = np.nan

# Last 2 values
N=2

for category in df.Category.unique():
    df_cat = df[df.Category==category]
    for idx, row in df_cat.iterrows():
        rm = df_cat[df_cat.Date_B < row.Date_A][:N].Value.mean()
        df.at[idx, 'rolling_mean'] = rm

df
```

```
  Category     Date_A     Date_B  Value  rolling_mean
0        A 2023-07-08 2023-07-08     10           NaN
1        A 2023-07-09 2023-07-10     15          10.0
2        A 2023-07-11 2023-07-12     20          12.5
3        A 2023-07-12 2023-07-12     25          12.5
4        A 2023-07-13 2023-07-13     30          12.5
5        B 2023-07-08 2023-07-08     35           NaN
6        B 2023-07-09 2023-07-10     40          35.0
7        B 2023-07-11 2023-07-12     45          37.5
8        B 2023-07-12 2023-07-12     50          37.5
9        B 2023-07-13 2023-07-13     55          37.5
```

Comment: Can you provide the exact expected output? Don't forget to define `N`

Comment: I added what N means and added a more detailed example, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not the most efficient way, but seems a little faster than the double for-loop:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Sample DataFrame (replace this with your actual DataFrame)
data = {
    'Category': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
    'Date_A': ['2023-07-08', '2023-07-09', '2023-07-11', '2023-07-12', '2023-07-13', '2023-07-08', '2023-07-09', '2023-07-11', '2023-07-12', '2023-07-13'],
    'Date_B': ['2023-07-08', '2023-07-10', '2023-07-12', '2023-07-12', '2023-07-13', '2023-07-08', '2023-07-10', '2023-07-12', '2023-07-12', '2023-07-13'],
    'Value': [10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55]
}


df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Convert 'Date_A' and 'Date_B' columns to datetime type
df['Date_A'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_A'])
df['Date_B'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_B'])
df['rolling_mean'] = np.nan

# Last 2 values
N=2

df["rolling_mean"] = df.groupby("Category").apply(
    lambda grp: grp["Date_A"].map(
        lambda a: grp.loc[grp.Date_B < a, "Value"].head(N).mean()
    ),
).droplevel(level="Category")

print(df)
```

```
  Category     Date_A     Date_B  Value  rolling_mean
0        A 2023-07-08 2023-07-08     10           NaN
1        A 2023-07-09 2023-07-10     15          10.0
2        A 2023-07-11 2023-07-12     20          12.5
3        A 2023-07-12 2023-07-12     25          12.5
4        A 2023-07-13 2023-07-13     30          12.5
5        B 2023-07-08 2023-07-08     35           NaN
6        B 2023-07-09 2023-07-10     40          35.0
7        B 2023-07-11 2023-07-12     45          37.5
8        B 2023-07-12 2023-07-12     50          37.5
9        B 2023-07-13 2023-07-13     55          37.5
```

## Time comparison via `%%timeit`

#### Original

```py
%%timeit
for category in df.Category.unique():
    df_cat = df[df.Category==category]
    for idx, row in df_cat.iterrows():
        rm = df_cat[df_cat.Date_B < row.Date_A][:N].Value.mean()
        df.at[idx, 'rolling_mean'] = rm
```

```
7.42 ms ± 277 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

#### Proposed

```py
%%timeit
df["rolling_mean"] = df.groupby("Category").apply(
    lambda grp: grp["Date_A"].map(
        lambda a: grp.loc[grp.Date_B < a, "Value"].head(N).mean()
    ),
).droplevel(level="Category")
```

```
4.55 ms ± 214 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

## Some explanation:

```py
# this handles the initial for-loop over "Categories"
# it returns an Iterator of tuples with the first 
# item being the group name and the second being the dataframe group
df.groupby("Category")
```

```py
# `grp` is the dataframe part returned by the `.groupby` above.
# it has the same columns as the original, but filtered down 
# to the rows in the selected group.
.apply(
    lambda grp: grp["Date_A"]...
)
```

```py
# `map` iterates over the values of the declared series (i.e. "Date_A")
# `a` is one of the values in "Date_A" and it is compared to the 
# series "Date_B".
# `grp` is filtered to the rows where "Date_B" is < `a`.
# we keep the first `N` rows of the returned dataframe and take the mean
.map(
        lambda a: grp.loc[grp.Date_B < a, "Value"].head(N).mean()
    )
```

```py
# we drop the newly generated "Category" index so we can join back 
# with the original `df`.
.droplevel(level="Category")
```

## References

- [`pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply.html)
- [`pandas.Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html)
- [`pandas.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the `Date_B` is always equal or greater than `Date_A`. Then you can try using `.groupby()` + `.expanding`:

```py
df['rolling_mean_2'] = (
    df.groupby("Category")
    .expanding()["Value"]
    .apply(
        lambda x: x[df.loc[x.index, "Date_B"] < df.loc[x.index[-1], "Date_A"]][:2].mean()
    ).values
)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Category     Date_A     Date_B  Value  rolling_mean  rolling_mean_2
0        A 2023-07-08 2023-07-08     10           NaN             NaN
1        A 2023-07-09 2023-07-10     15          10.0            10.0
2        A 2023-07-11 2023-07-12     20          12.5            12.5
3        A 2023-07-12 2023-07-12     25          12.5            12.5
4        A 2023-07-13 2023-07-13     30          12.5            12.5
5        B 2023-07-08 2023-07-08     35           NaN             NaN
6        B 2023-07-09 2023-07-10     40          35.0            35.0
7        B 2023-07-11 2023-07-12     45          37.5            37.5
8        B 2023-07-12 2023-07-12     50          37.5            37.5
9        B 2023-07-13 2023-07-13     55          37.5            37.5
```